# Parsing the author name(s) of a research paper using pdfminer

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, data-science, pdfminer

As much as the title, author, date, etc are apparent to the human eyes, I was thinking how to parse out such data for a folder of papers downloaded from SSRN. Most papers don't have metadata properly in them, so must be parsed from the title-page.

Obviously enough, most titles tend to have the largest font on the title page, so I try to identify the text positions having the max font size and assume they represent the title. Trying on a few files and it works fine but not always.

Author names don't seem to follow any particular pattern, so I don't know how to parse. Any idea or suggestion?

```
import sys
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextContainer, LTLine, LTChar



def getTitle(filepath):
    """method to extract the title of a pdf file"""
  
    try:
        filepath = filepath.strip()
    except TypeError:
        print("filepath not a string")
   
    if not filepath[len(filepath)-4:len(filepath)] == ".pdf":
        sys.exit("filepath not ending with .pdf")
      
    
    data = extractFirstPageElements(filepath)
    texts = data[0]
    fonts = data[1]

    if len(texts) == 0: #in case no text is read, either the pdf text is not readable or first page is blank
        title = "Unknown"
    else:
        maxFontPos = extractTitlePos(fonts)
        uncleanedTitle = extractTitle(texts, maxFontPos)
        title = cleanTitle(uncleanedTitle)
  
    return title


def extractFirstPageElements(filepath):
    """helper method to extract text elements and their corresponding font sizes into lists"""

    fonts = []
    elements = []
    for page in extract_pages(filepath):
        for element in page:
            if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
                for text_line in element:
                    for character in text_line:
                        if isinstance(character, LTChar):
                            font_size = character.size
                            break #the first character only, assuming all others in text_line have the same size
                fonts.append(font_size)
                elements.append(element.get_text())
        break #reading first page only
    return [elements, fonts]


def extractTitlePos(fonts):
    """helper method to extract the positions having the largest font size"""
    font_pos = []
    maxFont = max(fonts)
    for pos, size in enumerate(fonts):
        if size == maxFont:
            font_pos.append(pos)
    return font_pos


def extractTitle(elements, positions):
    """helper method to extract those elements having the largest font size, then return as a joint string"""
    title = []
    for i in positions:
        title.append(elements[i])
    return "".join(title)


def cleanTitle(title):
    """helper method to clean the title by removing \n and illegal filename symbols"""
    title = title.strip() #remove whitespaces
    title = title.replace("\n", " ") #remove any inline \n
    title = title.replace(":", " -") #replace invalid filename : symbol
    title = title.replace("?", " ") #replace invalid filename ? symbol
    return title

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filepath = input("Enter the file path (using /): ")
    print(getTitle(filepath))
```

Comment: It might be easier to get the author names by looking up the title from somewhere with an API, or maybe even [SSRN's own search tool](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/DisplayAbstractSearch.cfm)

Comment: That's true, given the un-patternable author names in a paper, unknown relative font size, unknown number of authors, unknown coordinates

Comment: "How do I get python to follow a rule I can't articulate" I think the right answer is 'train an AI to do this'... but I don't think that fits within the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.